# Iterate through nested classes in WWW::Selenium

Tags: html, perl, selenium, loops

Is there any method in `WWW::Selenium` which will allow me to iterate through this structure (HTML code) and access the hrefs?

```
<div class="myGengo_wrap full_width">
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="blue list">
    <span class="title">Sections </span>
        <span class="dashboard_master_language">
        <span class="dashboard_language wide">
            <a href="http://mygengo.com/string/p/demoproject-1/admin/languages/settings/en_us">Englisch (Master) </a>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dashboard_languages">
        <span class="dashboard_language wide">
            <a href="http://mygengo.com/string/p/demoproject-1/admin/languages/settings/zh_cn">Chinese </a>
        </span>
        <span class="dashboard_language wide">
            <a href="http://mygengo.com/string/p/demoproject-1/admin/languages/settings/de_de">German </a>
        </span>
    </span>
      ...
      ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a get_all_links method - see the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~lukec/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.33/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm).

Comment: I don't want all the links. I want to iterate only the classes under a particular class

Comment: Then you can write your own JavaScript code and run it with get_eval. Its tedious, but it works.